Old anime about a city in deep space that had to fight its way back to Earth
When I was a kid, I watched this anime with a similar art style to Space Carrier Blue Noah (1979–1980).
It was about this city that was in deep space and had to fight its way back to Earth. I think they eventually get there or something, but it had like little space battles and stuff. I don't remember if it was like a mech; I think it was a carrier.
More details are that it has this moving interior city that the main characters live in with civilians, and that it has these white orb thingies on the outside that move around the ship or whatever, that protect it from hits. I also believe they had planes and that they had this lockdown mode which warned everyone that the blocks in the city were moving into its combat mode.
This is all that I remember so far. I'll try to Renee rode and to follow up on this with any information I might remember.
My name is my Reddit user.
(Edit:it was robotech thanks yall)

In roughly which year did you watch this?

Robotech would fit the description, and the art style looks similar to the example you give. First shown in 1985  based on Japanese shows from 1982-1984.
The SDF-1 was a rebuilt alien ship. In the early episodes it undertakes a 'fold jump' to escape the aliens and accidentally drags a city (Macross island) with it. They end up near Pluto instead of the intended target of Earth's moon and have to fight their way back to Earth.
The city is rebuilt inside the ship with civilians living in it - the city changes causing significant issues the first time they reconfigure the ship to enable firing of the main weapon.



The ship has pinpoint barrier technology which appears as white circles intercepting incoming fire.



They also have Veritech fighters - they default to appearing to be fighter/interceptors, but can transform into other modes.

Unfortuately in the Harmony Gold English translation Lyn Minmei was a mediocre singer. Don't forget the other mech, go the M.A.C.H II !!! The white orbs were the ships shields, created with Prototech technology, controlled by a trackball in the bridge.
